# OptionalDataException while receiving large files using Apache Mina library on Android

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, codec, apache-mina

I am using Apache Mina to transfer objects between Java server and Android client. I am receiving the following error when transferring large files.

```
org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolDecoderException:
org.apache.mina.core.buffer.BufferDataException: java.io.OptionalDataException
(Hexdump: .........)
```

The same thing works perfectly with just Java client. But on Android I can only receive
small objects. Bigger will throw the exception.

I notice in my logs that Android is processing the object in three pieces. I see
`Processing a MESSAGE_RECEIVED for session 1` three times.

Can anybody help me find a workaround/solution for this?